# How do I pass value directly into a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angular directive I would like to pass value to.

```
 <div my-component binding-foo="foo">
    <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedBindingFoo}} // get it to output foo?
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS mangles HTML attributes to JS properties. eg, `binding-foo` in HTML will be mangled to `bindingFoo` in JS, and vice-versa

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.isolatedBindingFoo = '';

}])
.directive('myComponent', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E,A',
        controller: 'yourController',
        scope: true, 
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.isolatedBindingFoo = attrs['bindingFoo'];
        } 
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b2xo0o5u/3/

But in the example case this should be enough:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.directive('myComponent', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        scope: {
            'isolatedBindingFoo': '@bindingFoo'
        }
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b2xo0o5u/4/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div my-component binding='foo'> ... </div>
```

JS

```
yourApp.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.isolatedBindingFoo = '';

}])
.directive('myComponent', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'yourController',
        scope: {
            'binding': '=binding'
        }, 
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $scope.isolatedBindingFoo = attrs['binding'];
        } 
    } 
});
```

http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/passing-configuration-params-using-html-attributes.html

Cheers

Comment: That looks great, but I couldn't get it to work. And I am still confused about how binding works. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2xo0o5u/)

Comment: You need to remove the `-foo` from your attribute and just change it to `binding='foo'`. Here's an updated fiddle.

Comment: bah, sorry, I'm not too skilled with jsfiddle...point is...make sure the binding in your HTML matches the value in the `scope` property in the directive. In this case, I modified it to be just `binding`, but you can define it as `"binding-foo"` in your directive if you want. So `scope: { "binding-foo": "=binding-foo" } and then reference it as `attrs['binding-foo']` in your link function